# SQL Server Service Broker on a High Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, high-availability, service-broker

I'm using a instance with Microsoft SQL Server 2016 || Enterprise Edition and I need to enable Service Broker for my database with this sentence:

```
ALTER DATABASE DB SET ENABLE_BROKER;
```

The size of the database is approximately 3 TB and is on a AG Group, I saw two main options:
add the command with rollback immediate or to stop the sql service agent.

I think the best option for me is to stop the agent but I confused, It is necessary to stop the agent only in the primary node or I have to stop in primary & secondary nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason to stop the agent, you will need to take the database out of the AG, then run the command on the Primary with rollback immediate as you know -

```
--alter database [<dbname>] set enable_broker with rollback immediate;
```

Then, place the database back into the AG.  I know placing it back into the AG is painful due to the size but nothing to get around that unfortunately.